# Parse Push - badge management

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform

So i've integrated Parse push into my app and I need a way to manage badges.

The flow I require is as follows:
- Tap a notification in the area = open app and decrement badge value
- Select app from home screen = open app and clear badge, resetting to zero.
- If a new notification comes in the value should increment from zero if it has been reset to zero and increment from the auto value if badge was not cleared but decremented.

My biggest problem right now is that if I clear the badge using the Parse SDK then it will also clear the notifications area - it does both.

The solution to this is to call directly:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:-1];
```

The problem is that this does not change the badge counter for Parse API, leaving it in an upward only spiral.

I need a way to set Parse API badge to zero, clear the badge from app icon but keep the notifications in tact in the notification area.

Is this possible please?

What are the suggested flows for push notifications in apps? Is it correct to assume that many apps are tracking notifications sent and which ones have been read so as to manage the badge number properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, badges eventually need to be cleared, and a good time is
usually when your app is opened. Setting the badge property on the
current installation will update the application icon badge number
and ensure that the latest badge value will be persisted to the server
on the next save, so all you need to do is:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
  if (currentInstallation.badge != 0) {
    currentInstallation.badge = 0;
    [currentInstallation saveEventually];
  }
  // ...
}
```

Setting badge on [PFInstallation currentInstallation] will automatically set applicationIconBadgeNumber too.

Reference - http://blog.parse.com/2012/07/18/badge-management-for-ios/